# SharedPreferences: Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-sharedpreference

This is the whole code file
when running `getInstance()` on `SharedPreferences` it throws "Null check operator used on a null value" error. but works when `getInstance` is called in initState

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
  MyApp() {
    SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((value) {
      sharedPreferences = value;
    });
  }
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text(
            "${(widget.sharedPreferences != null) ? 
widget.sharedPreferences.getInt('count') ?? 'no count found' : ''}",
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () => setState(() {}),
                child: Text("setState"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
      }
}
```

Why does this happen ?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67437038/how-to-access-shared-preferences-string-in-build-method-flutter/67437266#67437266)

Comment: Means MyApp constructor will be called multiple times you say ?

Comment: Yes it will, flutter widgets build methods and constructors should be idempotent/side-effect-free. And when you do need side effects like async operations do that in the state that is preserved between rebuilds.

Comment: I had another Statefulwidget which is same as this but that works without errors. This other widget is called when a button is clicked (NewScreen)