# How can I save my data on screen, whenever i open it in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm trying to make a WhatsApp clone UI. Now, I'm receiving the contacts by the package `contacts_service`. Now the problem is, whenever I open the app, I fetch data from contacts each and every time, even If i switch from camera to main chat screen, I fetch data again. Can you please suggest me a way, from which I can save data on screen, once I have retrieved it. Also please tell me a way, how can I refresh my data, whenever new contact is added.

Comment: Probably you are fetching the data inside a build methos, am I right? If you are using future you could [move the call to the initState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67437038/how-to-access-shared-preferences-string-in-build-method-flutter/67437266#67437266)

Answer (score 1):

you can save data in a list and before fetching a data check that the contact list is empty and if the list is empty then fetch data otherwise do nothing eg.

```
List contactList=[];
getContacts(){
 if(contactList.isEmpty){
  print('call you method to fetch all contacts');
 }
}
```

and you can refresh your data by again calling your method through a refresh button from UI.

you can also use state management like [provider: ^5.0.0](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) and [get: ^4.1.4](https://pub.dev/packages/get) (recommended)
you can also store your contact on local storage like [shared_preferences: ^2.0.6](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) or [get_storage: ^2.0.2](https://pub.dev/packages/get_storage)

Answer (score 0):

Try simply using the shared preferences

https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

Answer (score 0):

Use shared preferences in your code :
Add the following when you need to save the data:

```
SharedPreferences 
data=awaitSharedPreferences.getInstance();
data.setString('your_key',your_data);
```

Add the following inside your main function before runApp function use async function:

```
SharedPreferences data = await 
SharedPreferences.getInstance();
var your_variable = data.getString('your_key');
```